# Select data attribute based on matching part

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

How to select all data attributes starting with `data-size-` in element like this one

```
<div class="el" data-name="str" data-size-100="str" data-size-158="str" data-size-304="str">str</div>
```

I'm trying to do something like, but can't figure it out:

```
$('.el').attr('[data-size-*]')
```

Comment: Do you want to get the value of all `data-size-*` in an object?

Comment: yes, all data sizes. Something like `el.attr('[data-size-*]').split(', ')`

Comment: Are there multiple elements having class `.el`?

Comment: no, only single element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `dataset`

```
var data = $('.el')[0].dataset;
var attrs = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(a,b){
 if(b.startsWith("size")){ a.push(data[b]); }
 return a;
},[]);

console.log(attrs); \\ ["str","str","str"]
```

Here I used `startsWith` to determine whether the data-'key' starts with a particular substring or not. Also `reduce` is to reduce the original key array to a new array based on the condition we have.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k4v8fpuw/)

Comment: Good! Suggestions: **1.** Use object with key-value to get the data attribute name and value. **2.** Remove jQuery dependency completely, use `querySelector()`. [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/k4v8fpuw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This one returns an array with objects holding both name and value.

```
var     myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("el")[0],
dataSizeAttrs = [];
Array.prototype.forEach.call(myDiv.attributes, e => 
  /data-size/.test(e.nodeName) && dataSizeAttrs.push({name : e.nodeName,
                                                      value: e.nodeValue}) );
```